# Phonegap Detect Device GPS Status

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, gps

After hours of search I finally decided to post a question here.

I am using cordova/phonegap version 3 library and trying to build an app based on geolocation.
What I need to do is to check if the user has their GPS enabled before they can do something else but this doesn't seems to be possible as far as i can see.

The code I am using is:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
   // Throw an error if no update is received every 30 seconds
   var options = {maximumAge: 0, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
   watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onGeoError, options);
}

function onSuccess(position) { 
    //DO WHATEVER
}

function onGeoError(error) {
   alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
   'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

I expect an error to be thrown with error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE message but no matter what I do TIMEOUT error (error.TIMEOUT) gets thrown every single time. I even put the device in flight mode with everything (gps, etc) turned off and still got TIMEOUT error.

Can anyone please suggest a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation

Comment: yes all the permissions are already added

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Yes, The problem with my application was that I didn't run the build command (cordova prepare) after installing the plugin. Backup your www folder before running 'cordova build' command as this will replace www folder with default content.

Comment: Sahil, it is better to add own answer and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my application was that I didn't run the build command (cordova prepare) after installing the plugin. Backup your www folder before running 'cordova build' command as this will replace www folder with default content